# How to map foreign key from dto to the entity object using ModelMapper?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, modelmapper

This is my userEntity

```
class UserEntity {
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

This is my user logins entity

```
class UserLoginEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    User user;
    String loginTime;
}
```

Assume one user can have many login time.
Below is the dto to add login time for the user

```
class UserLoginDto {
    Long user; //User id foreign key
    String loginTime;
}
```

Now I am unable to convert `UserLoginDto` to `UserLoginEntity` because in dto i am passing user as `Long` and it is expecting it to be of type `User`. Can this be done via model mapper utility?

Comment: You found some solution to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ModelMapper, then you need to name your attribute `userId` instead of `user`.

Or you can set the model mapper configuration to `LOOSE` like this:

`modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);` and rename `user` to `id`.

[Here](http://modelmapper.org/examples/flattening/#example-1) are some good examples on how you should create your DTOs and use them with `ModelMapper`